# How to get around HTTParty invalid code lengths set (Zlib::DataError)?

Tags: ruby, redirect, httparty

When sending an `HTTParty.get()` request to a URL that redirects to another (one, or possibly more) URL(s), I get this error:

```
Zlib::DataError:

       invalid code lengths set

     # ./file/file_name.rb:63:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

How do I get around this, and why is it happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the [`Accept-Encoding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding) param in the headers option to blank:

```
resp = HTTParty.get(article.old_url, :verify => false, :headers => {'Accept-Encoding' => ''})
```

HTTParty was having errors decompressing the response (specifically [gzip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) in my case), possibly because something strange was happening with the received [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding) header as a result of the redirect(s). Setting the Accept-Encoding header to blank returned something that HTTParty knew how to parse.